# How can i still use file after kubernetes mount using pv

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

When I created grafana pod to use official image and mounted /var/lib/grafana, data is not hidden
I don't know why?
According to what I have been studying if pvc is mounted in /var/lib/grafana directory, every file is hidden and can't access.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: grafana-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: grafana-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grafana
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grafana
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: grafana
          image: grafana/grafana:latest
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/var/lib/grafana"
            name: grafana-var
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 472
        fsGroup: 472
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: grafana-var
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteMany"]
        storageClassName: nks-nas-csi
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 2Gi
```

```
[dev1-user@master-dev-kube-cluster migration]$ k exec -it grafana-statefulset-0 -- sh
/usr/share/grafana $
/usr/share/grafana $ ls -l /var/lib/grafana/
total 912
drwxr-x---    3 grafana  root          4096 Jan  2 08:00 alerting
drwx------    2 grafana  root          4096 Jan  2 08:00 csv
drwxr-x---    2 grafana  root          4096 Jan  2 08:00 file-collections
-rw-r-----    1 grafana  root        909312 Jan  3 01:20 grafana.db
drwxr-xr-x    2 grafana  root          4096 Jan  2 08:00 plugins
drwx------    2 grafana  root          4096 Jan  2 08:00 png
```

But i can see and access well /var/lib/grafana directory data

However when I created the image separately, the files in the directories I mounted were hidden and inaccessible.

```
### First Stage
FROM busybox:latest

RUN mkdir /var/aaaa

COPY ./main.go /

RUN mv main.go /var/aaaa
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  serviceName: busybox
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: busybox
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: busybox
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: busybox
          image: busy/test:busybox
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          command:
          - sleep
          - "86400"
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/aaaa
            name: www
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: www
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteMany"]
        storageClassName: nks-nas-csi
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 2Gi
```

```
[dev1-user@master-dev-kube-cluster migration]$ k exec -it busybox-0 -- sh
/ #
/ #
/ # ls -l /var/aaaa/
total 0
/ #
```

There are no main.go file in /var/aaaa directory

The point of this article is not statefulset, it's just a question that came up while testing.

How can I keep using every directory data after mount like grafana official image and how grafana do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I keep using every directory data after mount like grafana official image and how grafana do that?

The official image only has `plugin` in `/var/lib/grafana`. Those additional directories that you saw; will automatically be created by grafana during start-up if not exist.